# Re-Enable Package Control in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublime-text-2

Using the "disable package" feature of the  Package Control extension in Sublime Text 2 I accidentally disabled Package Control itself, and now I'm not sure how to reenable it.  I'm guessing this is a setting stored somewhere, but for the life of me I can't find it.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove "Package Control" from "ignored_packages" inside of your Preferences file.

Go to `Preferences > Settings-User`. You should see something like:

```
"ignored_packages":
[
  "Vintage",
  "Package Control"
],
```

Make it:

```
 "ignored_packages":
[
  "Vintage"
],
```